# Are my ties to Germany strong enough to get a B2 visa?

Tags: paperwork, b1-b2-visas, russian-citizens, german-residents, proof-of-ties

I'm a 22-year-old female natural science international student in Germany who'll graduate from a German university this coming May, and will start grad school this coming autumn. I've been living in Germany since 2021 and was always employed part-time. I have enough money in my bank account to cover the cost of my stay (I selected myself as a trip sponsor in the DS-160). I'm single and have no property in Germany, my grad school will be fully funded and I have a confirmation of it as well.

In the DS-160 I mentioned that I'm visiting a male friend in CA, also added his address as a place where I'm planning to stay for 6 weeks in summer. I have a solid plan of what I'm planning to visit in CA (also mentioned in my application). Is it a red flag for the embassy? How high are my chances then? Do I have to bring all the documents for an interview? Some people say that it's better not to have a pile of paperwork.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: We're not the ones who have to make the decision so we can't really say how likely it is you'll receive the visa. But some things you don't touch here, but that might affect the outcome is: Where are you originally from? Why are you in Germany? Where is your family? Is your relationship with the male friend purely platonic?

Comment: *Do I have to bring all the documents for an interview?* You should take the Required Documents [see e.g](https://uk.usembassy.gov/visas/tourism-visitor/required-documents/) as a minimum, plus any others you believe are relevant. AFAIK you will be asked to show the documents deemed necessary to decide if you qualify for a visa under US law, but you shouldn’t try to submit anything that’s not requested by the IO at the interview

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity, i’m Russian, came to Germany to study and wanna stay for PhD and what’s not, my family is in Russia. I don’t know whether embassy can prove the last question

Comment: @MariiaZelenskaia I rather suspect the embassy might expect *you* to prove the last question. https://www.murthy.com/2017/06/29/nonimmigrants-must-overcome-presumption-of-immigrant-intent/

Comment: @Traveller thank you very! hope being in Germany for a while and being enrolled in a good grad school will be sufficient